# AngularJS $resource returns [d{...}]. What is it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

If I `console.log` [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), I get something back I don't understand.

```
$scope.results = $resource(url, {}, {withCredentials: true}).query(function(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
});
```

returns:

```
LOG: [d{id: '4', foo: 'bar'}]
```

What is the meaning of the 'd' inside the array?

Comment: Code review welcome in comments. I'm sure I could improve my work :).

Comment: It's not clear but is that console output the result of `console.log(arg)` as shown above or some other console command you haven't shown?

Comment: That's the output when I run jasmine specs :)

Comment: So this is in a test? How have you configured the response? Are you mocking `$resource` or setting up something on `$httpBackend`?

Comment: console.log returns the same thing if I run it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You execute an async function, and that function doesn't return real data, it returns a promise. Promise will be resolved after a response.

Take a look into [that post](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) and [another one](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/).

Long story short: You have to specify a function that will be called on promise resolve.

On your example:

```
$resource(url, {}, {withCredentials: true}).query(function(data) {
  $scope.results = data;
});
```

or:

```
$resource(url, {}, {withCredentials: true}).query().$promise.then(
    function(data) {
      $scope.results = data;
    }
);
```

If I remember that API correctly.

Comment: `$resource` actions do **not** *"return a promise"*. They return an empty instance that is later populated with data when the async action resolves.

Comment: sorry, you're right.
I use $http generally, so that's clearly a mistake.